# Manifest gives error once Remove BlackBerry Nature From Project

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-manifest, blackberry-android

I added BlackBerry Nature to Android Project and remove the BlackBerry Nature From Project. After that Android project Manifest shows error and not build the project. I did not do any changes on Manifest and just show error mark.

I closed the eclipse,clean and build the project but still same

How to solve this ?

Comment: can you paste your AndroidManifest.xml and the error messages?

Comment: no error just show the error mark on AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yes, the error message will show up if your mouse hover on it

Comment: its not shows that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I found a solution actually I don't know what happen but it worked.I change the **java compiler version to 1.5** and build the project, again I changed the **compiler to 1.6** and build the project **Then and only it fixed**. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the beginning of your  AndroidManifest.xml  ?

Comment: this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to prevent Blackberry plug-in from involving in making procedure.

Here are the steps:

1. open menu "Windows" -> "Preferences" -> "BlackBerry" -> "BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Development Tools"
2. under the title of "Verifier options" , un-check "Enable APK verifier ( checks ....) "
3. confirm the change by clicking on "Apply" button or "OK" button.
4. open menu "Windows" -> "Preferences" -> "BlackBerry"
5. under the title of "BlackBerry Reference" , check "Clean distribution folder("dist") when BlackBerry nature is removed"
6. it would be better to delete the BlackBerry Targets.